# SQL Having count logic

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, group-by, having

i need help on `HAVING COUNT` , i have a result set of data below:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTest1 (Code VARCHAR(50), Name VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO [#tmpTest1]
(
    [Code],
    [Name]
)
SELECT '160215-039','ROBIN'
UNION ALL SELECT '160215-039','ROBIN'
UNION ALL SELECT '160215-046','SENGAROB'
UNION ALL SELECT '160215-046','BABYPANGET'
UNION ALL SELECT '160215-045','JONG'
UNION ALL SELECT '160215-045','JAPZ'
UNION ALL SELECT '160215-044','AGNES'
UNION ALL SELECT '160215-044','AGNES'
UNION ALL SELECT '160215-041','BABYTOT'
UNION ALL SELECT '160215-041','BABYTOT'
UNION ALL SELECT '160215-041','BABYTOT'
```

i want to show only the rows that have the same `code` but different `name` , so in this case my expected result is below since those are have the same code but different name:

```
160215-045  JAPZ
160215-045  JONG
160215-046  BABYPANGET
160215-046  SENGAROB
```

but when i try to `group` the two columns then use the `having count`, below is my query:

```
SELECT [Code], [Name] FROM [#tmpTest1] 
GROUP BY [Code], [Name] HAVING COUNT([Code]) > 1
```

It gives me wrong result below which have the rows that have the same code and name, it is the opposite of what i want.

```
160215-044  AGNES
160215-041  BABYTOT
160215-039  ROBIN
```

How can i get my expected output ?

Thanks in advance, any help would much appreciated.

Comment: What if you had `'160215-041','BABYTOT', '160215-041','BABYTOT', '160215-041','OTHER'` ?  What would be returned in this case?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh i see, that is a good question , i didn't consider that one.. if that is the case , i want also to show that 3 records, i mean if there is 1 different name for the codes , i want to show those records for me to know that there is one differs to others.. but if the code and name is all the same, i don't want those in the result... can you give me advise or help me on the right query ? Thanks in advance Tim.

Comment: The query I gave below should meet your requirements then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this query will give you the result you want, although your original question is a bit unclear.

```
SELECT t1.[Code], t1.[Name]
FROM [#tmpTest1] t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT [Code]
    FROM [#tmpTest1] 
    GROUP BY [Code]
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Name]) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.[Code] = t2.[Code]
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de307/2)

Comment: this one works for me ..i'll mark this as answer.. thank you so much.. big help to me :) .. regards

Answer (score 2):

If you want rows with the same code and name, then use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by code, name) as cnt
      from #temptest1 t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

Comment: ahm nope.. i want same code but different name.. anyways appreciate your answer.

Comment: one up vote because your answer also help me in other report requirement of my project.. regards :)

Answer (score 1):

From your comment

> if there is 1 different name for the codes , i want to show those
>   records for me to know that there is one differs to others..

This sounds like an `exists` query because you want to check if another row with the same code but different name exists.

```
select * from [#tmpTest1] t1
where exists (
  select 1 from [#tmpTest] t2
  where t2.code = t1.code
  and t2.name <> t1.name
)
```

Comment: if only the unique records, then i think the distinct might have sufficed.